# Row level permissions for entities based on roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Using role based permissions, and say each row in a table represents an entity e.g. the Products table, each row represents a Product entity.

How could you provide Product level security based on roles?

e.g. the Sales group has access to Products with ID's 1,234,432,532,34

Multiple roles can be given permissions on any given product.

The goal is to provide an effecient database call for a query like:

```
var products = ProductDao.GetProductsByRole(234);  // roleID = 234
```

Answer (score 2):

Many-to-Many relations are stored in a separate table:

```
create table Products( 
    ProductId int not null identity (1,1),
    Name nvarchar(256) not null,
    Description nvarchar(max),
    constraint PK_Products primary key (ProductId),
    constraint UNQ_Products_Name unique (Name));

create table Roles(
    RoleId int not null identity (1,1),
    Name nvarchar(256) not null,
    Description nvarchar(max),
    constraint PK_Roles primary key (RoleId),
    constraint UNQ_Roles_Name unique (Name));
go

create table ProductRolePermissions (
    ProductId int not null,
    RoleId int not null,
    constraint FK_ProductRolePermissions_Products
        foreign key (ProductId) 
        references Products(ProductId),
    constraint FK_ProductRolePermissions_roles
        foreign key (RoleId) 
        references Roles(RoleId));
go

create unique clustered index CDX_ProductRolePermissions 
   on ProductRolePermissions (RoleId, ProductId);
create unique nonclustered index NDX_ProductRolePermissions 
   on ProductRolePermissions (ProductId, RoleId);
go


create function dbo.GetProductsByRole( @roleId int)
returns table
with schemabinding
as return (
    select ProductId 
    from dbo.ProductRolePermissions
    where RoleId = @roleId);
go


insert into Products (Name) 
       values ('P1'), ('P2'), ('P3'), ('P4');
insert into Roles (Name) 
       values ('G1'), ('G2');
insert into ProductRolePermissions (ProductId, RoleId) 
       values (1,1), (3,1), (2,2), (3,2);
go

select 'Products permitted for G1', p.* 
from dbo.GetProductsByRole(1) r
join Products p on r.ProductId = p.ProductId;

select 'Products permitted for G2', p.* 
from dbo.GetProductsByRole(2) r
join Products p on r.ProductId = p.ProductId;
```

Things get a little more complicated if you want to follow the classical grant/deny/revoke permission model for read/write/full access with multiple role memberships.

Comment: do you think is it the best solution for a table has more rows such as 100000 rows? if i implement your solution I think it causes more performance and user management problem. do you have any idea for my problem? tnx/